# A Canadian with a flat tire

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A Canadian gets a flat tire and is stuck on the side of the road. Name a thing such that if he does not have it, he will be in it.

Comment: This is nonsense. I'm Canadian and everybody knows that dogsleds don't need tires.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If he does not have

> a fix (a method of repair)

he will be in

> a fix (a difficult situation).

Comment: Not as punny as the answer I had in mind, but I like it!

Comment: I fear that I am missing is the "canadian-ness" of this answer...? Or is it implicit in the joke itself to refer to Canada without explicit reasons?

Comment: @KenDuna Now that you have already accepted an answer, I demand that you reveal the answer you had in mind.

Comment: Was it supposed to be a pun with the "Fix" body shops? www.fixauto.com

Comment: Not only does this answer have nothing to do with Canada, but it has nothing to do with a flat tire.  “A ***person*** … ***has a problem***.  Name a thing such that if he does not have it, he will be in it.”  The above answer fits this general question, showing that it is too broad (it answers too many possible questions).

Answer (score 42):

If he does not have

> a Canadian tire (a Canadian's tires are always Canadian, right?)

he will be in

> a Canadian Tire (the store).

Comment: This one's great

Comment: this one actually makes the "Canadian" part relevant. The accepted answer could apply to a Brit etc

Comment: Yeah, I was a little surprised to see that the "Canadian" was apparently irrelevant, judging by the other answers and even the OP's intended answer. I figured it might've been intended as a red herring? But if you're from Canada or have been there much, this is a pretty obvious connection.

Comment: There's a famous early data mining case study from Canadian Tire transaction analysis.  The strongest predictor of defaulting on a Canadian Tire credit card is if you bought a chrome skull accessory.  That's the kind of classroom detail that stays for *years*

Answer (score 36):

If he does not have

> Da spare

He will be in

> Despair

Comment: This answer is amazing.

Comment: This is a pathetic answer, saved only by virtue of being (apparently) correct :-(

Answer (score 8):

Bit of a stretch, but maybe...

> Loonie?
>
>  If he doesn't have a loonie (some money for roadside assistance), he'll go crazy and be put in a loony bin (madhouse)? This assumes that he's very, very passionate about his car.

Comment: A nice idea, but it doesn't relate to the guy being Canadian.

Comment: @einpoklum  A *loonie* is colloquial term for a Canadian one dollar coin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loonie

Answer (score 4):

If he doesn't have

> irons (as in tire irons)

then he'll be in

> irons. - sailing term for stalled and unable to maneuver under certain conditions

Answer (score 3):

This doesn’t exactly fit the question *as asked*,
but I believe that it fits the spirit of the question
better than any of the other answers,
other than [Robert Fraser’s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/37339/19765) and [Jefromi’s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/37346/19765).

If he does not have

> a “boot”; i.e., the storage compartment of a car,
> which typically holds the spare tire and the jack. 
> Note that U.S. Americans call this the “trunk”;
> I’m not sure which term is used in the U.K. and down under.

… then he will *not* be getting

> about (i.e., he will not be getting around; he will not be driving).
> Reportedly, Canadians pronounce “about” the same as “a boot”.

Answer (score 2):

if he does not yet have any

> hurry

he will be in a

> hurry

pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

If he doesn't have

> da spare (as in spare tire)

then he'll be in

> despair.

Comment: Dupe of [Adam Davis's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/37381/7717) (which was approximately 4 hours older).

Comment: As poster, I thought providing my intended solution was a good idea.

Comment: @TOOGAM This, being the intended answer, was edited into the question and then removed before that answer was posted.

Comment: @KenDuna I think it would be fairer to accept the intended answer...

Comment: This has very little to do with the motorist being Canadian. It is based on [widely-used English language slang/lingo](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=DA&defid=61354), which is related to a multitude of regions, including Brooklyn, Chicago, Pittsburgh, and Minnesota.

Comment: @KenDuna It would be better to comment on Adam's answer that it is the intended one, rather than adding a duplicate answer.